# Unable to send image from Collection View Controller to Detail View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

What I have is an array of file names.
Here is the code that i have used to fill Collection View Cells.

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *dataPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/DrawnImage"];
NSArray *contentOfDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:NULL];


NSString *fileName = [contentOfDirectory objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSString *path = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];


UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImageView *cellImageView =  cell.collectionImageView;
cellImageView.image = image;   

return cell;
```

}

The images are being correctly displayed in the cells. What i want to do it, when i click on a cell, The picture in that cell must be displayed in full screen in a detail view controller.

I have tried this.

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *dataPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/DrawnImage"];
    NSArray *contentOfDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:NULL];
    NSString *fileName = [contentOfDirectory objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.item];
    NSString *pathToImage = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];
    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    dvc.finalImage = sender;
    NSLog(@"%@", backgroundImageView);


}
```

}

finalImage is an UIImageView in Detail View Controller. I get a run time error when i click one of the cells. What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

This is the code that I have right now.

CollectionViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *sendImage;
```

CollectionViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *dataPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/DrawnImage"];
    NSArray *contentOfDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:NULL];
    NSString *fileName = [contentOfDirectory objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.item];
    NSString *pathToImage = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];
    DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    dvc.passedInImage = image;
    image = dvc.passedInImage;
}
}
```

DetailViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *finalImage;
@property UIImage *passedInImage;
```

DetailViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

self.finalImage.image = passedInImage;
}
```

Comment: can you paste the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a couple of things wrong. First, sender in the prepareForSegue method will be the UICollectionViewCell that you clicked on, and you're trying to assign that to a UIImage view. That can't be done. However, even if the sender was an imageView, this isn't what you want to do. At the time that prepareForSegue executes, the view for the detail controller has not yet been loaded, so you can't access any of its outlets. What you should do, is create a UIImage property in the detail controller, lets call it *passedInImage for example. In prepareForSegue, assign image to the property:

```
dvc.passedInImage = image;
```

Then, in dvc, probably in viewDidAppear, set the image of finalImage to passedInImage.

Comment: Agree with your initial point about sender (see my earlier answer).  Regarding view loading, we're guessing about names, but finalImage sounds like an image, not an image view (OP would have a compiler warning unless it said dvc.finalImage.image = image).

Comment: @danh, the OP said in his question that finalImage is an image view.

Comment: yes it does.  my bad.  I've seen other answers from you... should have realized you would add something high quality.

Comment: I have added 
        dvc.passedInImage = image;
when i log dvc.passedInImage, I get <UIImage: 0xa4a2740>.
In DetailViewController.h , I have added
@property UIImage *passedInImage; and synthesised it.

In viewDidLoad, i have added "self.finalImage = passedInImage;"
But, this gives me a warning, assigning to UIImageView * from UIImage *
Also, the image is not being displayed. Am I doing it right?

Comment: @user2229411, No, you're not doing it right. finalImage (that's a bad name by the way), is an image view, so you need to set its image, not set it equal to an image: self.finalImage.image = passedInImage;

Comment: when i replace self.finalImage = passedInImage; with self.finalImage.image = passedInImage; in -viewDidAppear, the app crashes when i click a click. the erroe message is *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9480e40'

Comment: @user2229411, try logging passedInImage in dvc right above where you have the line self.finalImage.image = passedInImage; and see what that returns

Comment: I get  <UIImageView: 0xa1b47f0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa1b42c0>> - (null) @rdelmar

Comment: @user2229411, so passedInImage is an imageView?? You said a couple of comments ago, "when i log dvc.passedInImage, I get <UIImage: 0xa4a2740>". So, I have no idea what you're doing wrong now. You should edit your question to show what code you have now.

Comment: @user2229411, I don't see anything wrong with that code you posted. You should add the logs you added as well, so I can see where they are. What you say you're seeing in the logs doesn't make sense from the code I'm seeing.

Comment: @rdelmar, When i log dvc.passedInImage at the end of -prepareForSegue, i get <UIImage: 0xa155570> .When i log passedInImage in -viewDidLoad in DetailViewController, i get <UIImageView: 0xa151650; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa1551c0>> - (null).

Comment: @user2229411, I can't make any sense of that. That shouldn't be possible. You should remove this line: image = dvc.passedInImage; as the last line of prepareForSegue -- I don't think that's your problem, but that line is unnecessary.

Comment: All of a sudden it works? What I did was add the following line of code in the -viewDidLoad of DetailViewController. self.finalImage.image = passedInImage; Thank you so much for your time and patience. +1, Accepted. @rdelmar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27395/discussion-between-user2229411-and-rdelmar)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine, except `dvc.finalImage = sender;`

This looks from the var name that you're setting an image property, but sender is probably a collection view cell.  Do you want to use `backgroundImageView` instead?